# SyntaxError: Unexpected token '<' on new build of React

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a React application and every time I deploy it to production I'm getting this error `SyntaxError: Unexpected token '<'`, but once you reload the page there's no error and it loads properly. From my knowledge, it's because it's trying to locate the cached versions of the build files, but does anyone know how to fix this issue? Or bust the cache so that whenever I deploy, people don't get broken pages until the reload?

I run `env-cmd -f .env.production react-scripts build` to create a new production build before deploying the code.

package.json

```js
{
    "name": "react-app",
    "version": "0.1.0",
    "private": true,
    "proxy": "https://50874c4689b8.ngrok.io",
    "dependencies": {
        "@alexcambose/react-infinite-scroll": "^1.0.1",
        "@emotion/react": "^11.10.4",
        "@emotion/styled": "^11.10.4",
        "@mui/icons-material": "^5.10.3",
        "@mui/lab": "^5.0.0-alpha.98",
        "@mui/material": "^5.10.4",
        "@mui/styles": "^5.10.3",
        "@stripe/react-stripe-js": "^1.6.0",
        "@stripe/stripe-js": "^1.20.3",
        "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^5.11.4",
        "@testing-library/react": "^11.1.0",
        "@testing-library/user-event": "^12.1.10",
        "@tinymce/tinymce-react": "^3.12.6",
        "@types/array-move": "^2.0.0",
        "@types/axios": "^0.14.0",
        "@types/draftjs-to-html": "^0.8.1",
        "@types/html-to-draftjs": "^1.4.0",
        "@types/jest": "^26.0.22",
        "@types/node": "^12.20.7",
        "@types/react": "^17.0.3",
        "@types/react-bootstrap": "^0.32.25",
        "@types/react-dom": "^17.0.3",
        "@types/react-draft-wysiwyg": "^1.13.3",
        "@types/react-icons": "^3.0.0",
        "@types/react-infinite-scroll-component": "^5.0.0",
        "@types/react-infinite-scroller": "^1.2.2",
        "@types/react-redux": "^7.1.16",
        "@types/react-sortable-hoc": "^0.7.1",
        "@types/react-toastify": "^4.1.0",
        "@types/redux-logger": "^3.0.8",
        "@types/redux-persist": "^4.3.1",
        "@types/redux-thunk": "^2.1.0",
        "@types/socket.io-client": "^3.0.0",
        "@types/styled-components": "^5.1.9",
        "array-move": "^3.0.1",
        "axios": "^0.21.1",
        "axios-hooks": "^2.6.1",
        "bootstrap": "^4.6.0",
        "draftjs-to-html": "^0.9.1",
        "env-cmd": "^10.1.0",
        "formik": "^2.2.6",
        "gatsby-plugin-react-helmet": "^3.10.0",
        "gatsby-plugin-react-helmet-async": "^1.2.1",
        "html-to-draftjs": "^1.5.0",
        "laravel-echo": "^1.11.3",
        "laravel-echo-server": "^1.6.3",
        "moment": "^2.29.1",
        "moment-timezone": "^0.5.34",
        "node-sass": "^7.0.1",
        "pusher-js": "^7.0.6",
        "react": "^17.0.2",
        "react-adsense": "^0.1.0",
        "react-apple-signin-auth": "^1.0.0",
        "react-bootstrap": "^1.5.2",
        "react-device-detect": "^2.1.2",
        "react-dom": "^17.0.2",
        "react-draft-wysiwyg": "^1.14.7",
        "react-facebook-login": "^4.1.1",
        "react-ga": "^3.3.0",
        "react-google-button": "^0.7.2",
        "react-google-login": "^5.2.2",
        "react-helmet": "^6.1.0",
        "react-helmet-async": "^1.3.0",
        "react-icons": "^4.2.0",
        "react-infinite-scroll-component": "^6.1.0",
        "react-moment": "^1.1.1",
        "react-redux": "^7.2.3",
        "react-scripts": "^5.0.1",
        "react-select": "^5.4.0",
        "react-sliding-side-panel": "^2.0.3",
        "react-smartbanner": "^5.1.4",
        "react-sortable-hoc": "^2.0.0",
        "react-toastify": "^7.0.4",
        "recharts": "^2.1.10",
        "redux-logger": "^3.0.6",
        "redux-persist": "^6.0.0",
        "redux-thunk": "^2.3.0",
        "socket.io-client": "^4.1.3",
        "styled-components": "^5.2.2",
        "typescript": "^4.2.3",
        "web-vitals": "^1.0.1",
        "webpack": "^5.74.0",
        "yup": "^0.32.9"
    },
    "resolutions": {
        "@types/react": "17.0.3",
        "@types/react-dom": "17.0.3"
    },
    "scripts": {
        "start": "env-cmd -f .env.development react-scripts start",
        "start:prod": "env-cmd -f .env.production react-scripts start",
        "build": "react-scripts build",
        "build:prod": "env-cmd -f .env.production react-scripts build",
        "test": "react-scripts test",
        "eject": "react-scripts eject"
    },
    "eslintConfig": {
        "extends": [
            "react-app",
            "react-app/jest"
        ]
    },
    "browserslist": {
        "production": [
            ">0.2%",
            "not dead",
            "not op_mini all"
        ],
        "development": [
            "last 1 chrome version",
            "last 1 firefox version",
            "last 1 safari version"
        ]
    },
    "devDependencies": {
        "@types/react-facebook-login": "^4.1.3",
        "@types/react-router-dom": "^5.1.7",
        "react-router-dom": "^5.2.0"
    }
}
```

src/reportWebVitals

```js
import { ReportHandler } from "web-vitals";

const reportWebVitals = (onPerfEntry?: ReportHandler) => {
    if (onPerfEntry && onPerfEntry instanceof Function) {
        import("web-vitals").then(
            ({ getCLS, getFID, getFCP, getLCP, getTTFB }) => {
                getCLS(onPerfEntry);
                getFID(onPerfEntry);
                getFCP(onPerfEntry);
                getLCP(onPerfEntry);
                getTTFB(onPerfEntry);
            }
        );
    }
};

export default reportWebVitals;
```

src/index.tsx

```js
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
import App from "./App";
import reportWebVitals from "./reportWebVitals";
import { Provider } from "react-redux";
import { persistor, store } from "./store";
import { PersistGate } from "redux-persist/integration/react";
import SmartBanner from "react-smartbanner";
import { isMobile } from "react-device-detect";
import "react-smartbanner/dist/main.css";

//imports for toastify css
import "react-toastify/dist/ReactToastify.css";

//import react sliding panel css
import "react-sliding-side-panel/lib/index.css";

//import my css last to overwrite anything above it
import "./index.css";

//imports for yup
import "core-js/es/promise";
import "core-js/es/set";
import "core-js/es/map";
import "core-js/es/array";

const userAgent = navigator.userAgent || navigator.vendor;
let device = undefined;
if (/android/i.test(userAgent)) {
    device = "android";
} else if (/iPad|iPhone|iPod/.test(userAgent)) {
    device = "ios";
}

ReactDOM.render(
    <Provider store={store}>
        <SmartBanner
            force={isMobile ? device : undefined}
            title="React-App"
        />
        <PersistGate loading={null} persistor={persistor}>
            <App />
        </PersistGate>
    </Provider>,
    document.getElementById("root")
);

reportWebVitals();
```

App.tsx

```js
import { useEffect } from "react";
import { useDispatch, useSelector } from "react-redux";
import { ThemeProvider } from "styled-components";
import { Elements } from "@stripe/react-stripe-js";
import { loadStripe } from "@stripe/stripe-js";
import ReactGA from "react-ga";
import { HelmetProvider, Helmet } from "react-helmet-async";

import PublicRouter from "./router/Public";
import { RootState } from "./store";
import { setTheme } from "./store/theme/actions";
import { ThemeState } from "./store/theme/types";

import darkTheme from "./themes/dark";
import lightTheme from "./themes/light";

import "bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css";
import "./styles/app.scss";

declare module "styled-components" {
    interface DefaultTheme extends ThemeState {}
}

ReactGA.initialize("UA-xxxxxxx-x");
ReactGA.pageview(window.location.pathname + window.location.search);
const stripePromise = loadStripe("pk_live_xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx");

function App() {
    const dispatch = useDispatch();
    const user = useSelector((state: RootState) => state.user);
    const theme = useSelector((state: RootState) => state.theme);
    const subscription = useSelector((state: RootState) => state.subscription);

    useEffect(() => {
        dispatch(setTheme(user.dark_mode ? darkTheme : lightTheme));
        document.body.style.backgroundColor = theme.primary;
    }, [user.dark_mode]);

    useEffect(() => {
        if (subscription) {
            // Get the element you want to remove
            var element = document.querySelectorAll(".google-ads-script");
            // Get the parent and remove the element since it is a child of the parent
            if (element) {
                element.forEach((ele) => {
                    ele.remove();
                });
            }
        }
    }, [subscription]);

    return (
        <HelmetProvider>
            <ThemeProvider theme={theme}>
                <Elements stripe={stripePromise}>
                    {!subscription && (
                        <Helmet>
                            <script
                                id="google-ads-script"
                                async
                       src="https://pagead2.googlesyndication.com/pagead/js/adsbygoogle.js?client=ca-pub-xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"
                                crossorigin="anonymous"
                            ></script>
                        </Helmet>
                    )}
                    <PublicRouter />
                </Elements>
            </ThemeProvider>
        </HelmetProvider>
    );
}

export default App;
```

Comment: Do you have "homepage" in your package.json?

Comment: Is there an error when you "serve -s build" it on your local or it only breaks on the hosting? What hosting are you using for this?

Comment: @AifosSiPrahs there are no errors locally when "serve -s build". I don't have "homepage" in my package.json. I'm using digital ocean for hosting

Comment: Can you share your code repo or create a CodeSandbox? Also, are you using web-vitals.js? There're a lot of issues on GH in create-react-app repo, just want to have an idea of what you're using in your project that might cause that

Comment: @AifosSiPrahs Added package.json, reportWebVitals and my index file. Does that help?

Comment: I'll have a look, thanks!

Comment: in your App.tsx do use you React Router or there's no routing?

Comment: Does it work when you remove the proxy field from the package.json?

Comment: https://www.reddit.com/r/reactjs/comments/g5lfsc/comment/fo42x48/?utm_source=share&utm_medium=web2x&context=3

Please have a look at this comment, it looks like the proxy might be causing an error.

Are you really using that ngrok proxy?

Comment: That's probably due to the proxy

Comment: @AifosSiPrahs I'm not using that proxy. I removed it. Also, yes I'm using React Router. I tested it out without the proxy and still getting the same issue

Comment: Can you also add the App.tsx?

Comment: @AifosSiPrahs sure, just added it

Comment: I'm having a look at it, does it work if you deploy it on Firebase/Heroku after the build? I'm pretty sure it's related to Digital Ocean. As I don't have the full code of your project, I cannot test the Digital Ocean deployment myself. Can you turn the caching off?

Comment: @pbrune, i am also facing this same issue. But I am using AWS ECS. Whenever i push a new build, it will show this error until browser clear cache and refresh. Did you find any solution for this?

Comment: @Sydney unfortunately, no I have not found a solution to this yet